# What does Dirac delta function of a constant mean?

Tags: dirac-delta

I have seen a formula that unit step function is the integration of Dirac delta function.

$$H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \delta(t)~\mathrm dt $$

In evaluating the integral if we take the integral as sum of infinite terms ,what does delta function of  a constant represent?

Comment: The Dirac delta function of a constant (not equal to zero) is of course zero.

Comment: Keep in mind that Dirac delta is actually a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), not a function.  So it is not something that can be evaluated in the sense of Riemann integrals.

Comment: If you integrate it multiplied together with a function it "picks out" the value at t=0 of that function. Well, assuming 0 is in the interval of integration of course.

Comment: That image hurts to look at... so pixelated.  We have the ability to type with $\LaTeX$ here.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn more about how to properly typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to use the classical idea of Riemann integration, where integration is a limit of more and more, thiner and thiner rectangles.

Comment: I think that for intuition, it's often helpful to think of the $\delta$-function as being just an ordinary smooth function which is zero everywhere except for an extremely narrow spike at the origin. The spike is so tall that the area under the curve is $1$.

Answer (score 4):

The $\delta$-function is not actually a function - [it's a distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). The idea of finding an integral by using lots of thin rectangles doesn't work here. This is a more abstract form of integration. In fact, lots of integrals from Quantum Mechanics do not converge in the classical sense.

The $\delta$-function has the property that $\delta(x) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

So, for example, $\delta(2) = 0$ and $\delta(-3.4)=0$.

The value of $\delta(0)$ is not well-defined, but we do know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)~\mathrm dx = 1$$

Since $\delta(x) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, the values of $x$ away from zero contribute nothing to the integral:

$$\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \delta(x)~\mathrm dx = 1$$

for any $\varepsilon > 0$, as small as you like!

If $S$ is some open subset of the real numbers then
$$\int_S \delta(x)~\mathrm dx \ \ = \ \ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & : & 0 \in S \\ 0 & : & 0 \notin S \end{array}\right.$$

In fact, you can make even stronger statements, e.g. $S$ doesn't need to be open, but you need to be careful how you word it.

In your example

$$H(x) := \int_{-\infty}^{x} \delta(\tau)~\mathrm d\tau$$
the set $S$ is the interval $(-\infty,x)$. If $x < 0$ then $0 \notin S$ and so $H(x) = 0$ for all $x < 0$. If $x>0$ then $0 \in S$ and so $H(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$. What happens when $x=0$ depends on whom you speak to.

Comment: Why do you write things such as $$\delta(x)$$ after a first paragraph which explains (correctly) that, whatever $\delta$ is, $\delta$ is **not a function**?

Comment: How would you give meaning to $H(0)$? $\frac{1}{2}$ or  1 or  no value at all?

Comment: @Did It's a commonly used abuse of notation. It kind of makes sense if you think of the $\delta$-function as the limit of the Gaussian functions

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0^+} \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\alpha\pi}} \mathrm e^{-x^2/4\alpha} \right)$$

Comment: Sorry but I am not the one you should explain what $\delta$ is, to. The OP asks for the details of $\delta$ hence every slip of language, even one which is used by the experts, is detrimental here.